# how to assign a different name in while loops?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class java
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("3 random numbers are being generated!");
        int max=10;
        int min=1;
        int number1=(int)(Math.random()*max+min);
        int number2=(int)(Math.random()*max+min);
        int number3=(int)(Math.random()*max+min);
        System.out.println("what is the sum?");
        Scanner kb=new Scanner (System.in);
        int sum=number1+number2+number3;
        int entered=kb.nextInt();
        int i=1;
        while(sum!=entered){
            i++;
            System.out.println("please try again");
            int entered i=kb.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code and I want to do a while loop to create random numbers then you enter the answer, if it is wrong you can reenter it. I don't know how to do it though and where I have gone wrong.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish on this line? `int entered i=kb.nextInt();` This wouldn't even compile.

Comment: You're looking for arrays.

Comment: This line `int entered i=kb.nextInt();` should be `entered=kb.nextInt();`

Comment: What do you even want to do with `i`? Remove it if it's not required.

Comment: it has been answered I needed I otherwise it would be overriding the previous variable

Answer (score 2):

i think you need to change

```
int entered i=kb.nextInt();
```

to

```
entered=kb.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring two `entered` variables in one scope. If I have understood you right you want the user to enter numbers till he guess the right sum. So something like this may help you:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class java
{
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
          System.out.println("3 random numbers are being generated!");
          int max=10;
          int min=1;
          int number1=(int)(Math.random()*max+min);
          int number2=(int)(Math.random()*max+min);
          int number3=(int)(Math.random()*max+min);
          System.out.println("what is the sum?");
          Scanner kb=new Scanner (System.in);
          int sum=number1+number2+number3;
          int entered=kb.nextInt();
          int i=1;
          while(sum!=entered){
             i++;
             System.out.println("please try again");
             entered=kb.nextInt();
          }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code, it works:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Java
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("3 random numbers are being generated!");
        int max=10;
        int min=1;
        int number1=(int)(Math.random()*max+min);
        int number2=(int)(Math.random()*max+min);
        int number3=(int)(Math.random()*max+min);
        System.out.println("what is the sum?");
        Scanner kb=new Scanner (System.in);
        int sum=number1+number2+number3;
        int entered=kb.nextInt();
        while(sum!=entered){
            System.out.println("please try again");
            entered = kb.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```